# Generate list of prefix codes without building huffman tree

Tags: encoding, compression, prefix, huffman-code

I was unable to find algorithms that generate prefix codes without building a huffman tree. Are there any algorithms I could use to enumerate all short prefix codes upto a certain maximum value.
I am looking for something that looks like:

```
/*Sample prefix codes
* 0 - 0
* 1 - 101
* 2 - 111
*max - (Another prefix code)
*/


void GeneratePrefixCodes(int maxValue)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < maxValue; i++)
  {
    /*Generate prefix code for value i*/
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Easy. For each `i`, write `i` 1's, followed by one 0. If you would like for the code to be complete (no unused bit sequences), then for the last `i`, write `i` 1's.

E.g. for `maxValue` equal to 5, you get:

```
0
10
110
1110
1111
```